Why is the deletion ungrammatical in "I like the girl [who is] the prettiest in my class" but grammatical in other sentences?
One of my ESL friends is having trouble understanding a question in their English app. I am not good at grammar, so though I can tell them which answer is correct, I cannot explain why. I hope somebody can help me explain to them why #2 is the correct answer.
Question: Which of the following is grammatically incorrect when the bolded portion is removed?

I was happy to see the child who was talking to Mr. Smith.
I like the girl who is the prettiest in my class.
Messi is the player that I like best.
The car which is parked here is not mine.

As a native speaker, #2 feels like it is missing something when the bolded portion is excluded, but the other options still feel natural. As an American Idiot, I don't know why it feels wrong.
What is the correct way of explaining why #2 is the correct answer?

Note that in the case of your first sentence, the removing could change how the sentence gets understood. Presented as here outside any context, the version without who was is likely to be interpreted to mean that the speaker was happy to see that the child was speaking to Mr. Smith. The version retaining the who was would likely be given the meaning that would align with an answer to the question, “Which child were you happy to see?”

Whiz deletion. 2 gets an additional adjective transform to become "I like the prettiest girl in my class." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whiz_deletion

Would that not be construed as an ellipsis of “I like the girl [to be] the prettiest in my class”, as are most cases of “I want/like/prefer/expect/presume ⟨noun phrase⟩ ⟨adjective phrase⟩”?

In [1] and arguably [4], be ('was' / 'is') is the auxiliary usage, whereas in (2) it (in the form 'is') is copular.
Copular sentences with nounal, or (many) adjectival, complements can't be 'whiz-deleted'. Doing so would remove the required verbal element:

I saw the man who will be president one day. ⇸  ● I saw the man president one day.
I saw the horse which is troublesome. ⇸  ● I saw the horse troublesome.

But this has to be caveatted:

I saw the man who is afraid. and ● I saw the man afraid.

are both grammatical, but have different meanings ('I saw the man in a state of fear' [not the identifier reading: put 'John' for 'the man'] for the second).
And

I saw the car that was burned. [with identifying relative clause]

is 'whiz-deletable' to

I saw the car burned.

but changes meaning from the (stative) participial adjective [identifier usage] to the (punctive) participle, 'I saw the car being burned'.
'I saw the car burned by the rebels' is ambiguous and may be a reduced form of 'I saw the car that was burned by the rebels.' [whiz-deletion] or 'I saw the car being burned by the rebels' [be-deletion].
Other copular complements

I saw the referee [who is] here. [locative]
I saw the referee [who is] in charge of the match. [prepositional phrase]

can be whiz-deleted.
.....................................
To avoid the issue of whether whiz-deletion should be rejected, I'll use the looser definition, 'the deletion of a wh-word plus an adjacent form of 'be' from a sentence containing one, with no implication that this is anything other than a contrivance ... certainly not a claim that a significant grammatical process is involved'
......................................
Sentence [3] is of a totally different form. 'That' deletion (here of the subordinator incarnation of 'that') is in play; this has certainly been covered before on ELU.

this has certainly been covered before on ELU. How about a few links to help the man? He admits he doesn't know why no.2 needs the relative pronoun, and you talk to him about whiz-deletion. It seems you are quoting from someone or something in the "looser definition",  is that true?

I think greater explanation is needed to explain the difference between an essential clause (defining) from a non-essential one (non-defining)

I'm sorry, but -1 this time. A few reasons. First, it's besides the point whether be is an auxiliary or not in (4) - which should be clear enough because your 'arguably'. presumably arises from the fact that you can tell that either the verb or adjective are possible. Second reason is that the verb see is not a suitable verb to use here because it can take VPs as complements. These are in no way derived from be deletion (adding be would change the meaning as well as the structure!)

I stipulated my usage here of 'deletions': 'crossing out' certain words in a given sentence. Some argue that the term 'whiz deletion' is itself improper. //Call it 'to be scratching' / 'be scratching' if you like.
